# How can I generate instances of a class in Matlab and save them in an array?

Tags: matlab, object, save, instances

I started a code where I have to generate a lot of instances of a given class. I want to save them into an array like I would do in python.

This is what I want to do:

```
   object_list = [];
   for i=1:100
      my_object = MyClass(i)
      object_list(i) = my_object
   end
```

In Python this works because I can just append whatever I want to my list.
How should I do this in Matlab?

/The error is get is this:
"Conversion to double from MyClass is not possible."
I guess the Matlab array behaves differently than a generic python list, and actually needs to contain doubles. /

Comment: You can definitely append in MATLAB as well but appending is not really a good idea. A better approach is to pre-allocate to expected length. For your case, you'd need a cell array. So initialise a cell array of expected size i.e. `object_list=cell(1,100)` and replace `object_list(i)` with `object_list{i}` i.e. curly braces. The reason for doing that change is exactly what the error message suggests. (Also avoid using `i` (and `j`) as variable names since they represent imaginary numbers by default)

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize your array as an array of objects:

```
object_list(100) = MyClass(100);
for i=1:100
   object_list(i) = MyClass(i);
end
```

More information on [Initialize Object Arrays](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/initialize-object-arrays.html).